# How to base Typescript types off of the value of other props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

Is it possible to change the typescript prop type based off the runtime value of another prop?

For example

```
type MyComponent = {
   propA: boolean | string
   propB: typeof propA boolean ? number : string
}
```

something like this where based off another prop I then determine what prop type propB should be. I guess I can't do this because of runtime.

What would be the solution to that? I don't want to open up both props to have multiple types

The only solution I've got so far is to have separate distinct props that I use for my two different component cases

To make it clear I've got a wrapper around `<ReactSelect />` and I want to pass in different types for the `onChange` function based off of if the `isMulti` prop is true or not as the docs say that the values should be different.

==EDIT==

```
type SelectWithQueryPropsSingle<Variables, OnQueryData> = {
  onQuery: (data: OnQueryData, value: Option) => Array<Option>
  value: Option
} & SelectWithQueryConsistentProps<Variables>

type SelectWithQueryPropsMulti<Variables, OnQueryData> = {
  onQuery: (data: OnQueryData, value:  Array<Option>) => Array<Option>
  value: Array<Option>
} & SelectWithQueryConsistentProps<Variables>
```

when I call this:

`onQuery(data, value)` TS complains saying:

`Argument of type 'Option | Option[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Option & Option[]'.`

so in this instance why is the union failing to marry up value with the value argument?

```
export const SelectWrapper = <QueryType, Variables, OnQueryData>({
  // quite a few other props here but not listing them out
  onQuery,
}:
  | SelectWithQueryPropsSingle<Variables, OnQueryData>
  | SelectWithQueryPropsMulti<Variables, OnQueryData>)
```

```
type SelectWithQueryPropsSingle<Variables, OnQueryData> = {
  onQuery: (data: OnQueryData, value: Option) => Array<Option>
  value: Option
} & SelectWithQueryConsistentProps<Variables>

type SelectWithQueryPropsMulti<Variables, OnQueryData> = {
  onQuery: (data: OnQueryData, value: Array<Option>) => Array<Option>
  value: Array<Option>
} & SelectWithQueryConsistentProps<Variables>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach would be to use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types).

```
type MyComponent = {
  propA: boolean
  propB: number 
} | {
  propA: string
  probB: string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAWQgYQPYFsqoHY22OAXjgG9Q44oAnVKAQQC44AjVVAGxgENtzKaoAISbYArumYwqcUAF84AH1J9qtRnADOYKgEtsAcxU1mwzdr2GQsoA)

Comment: ok that makes sense but check out my edit to see why union is failing in my use case

Comment: @RedBaron - how are you using `SelectWithQueryPropsMulti` and `SelectWithQueryPropsMulti`? Can you show the code?

Comment: see further edits. many thanks

Comment: the editor seems to put a weird `|` before the first type when the name is too long

Comment: @RedBaron - I am still having trouble reproducing the exact error you are having. Could you add the missing types `Option` and `SelectWithQueryConsistentProps` and please also show where you call `onQuery(data, value)` and what the type of `data` and `value` are.

Comment: I've sort of replicated it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-typescript-forked-910rsc?file=/src/App.tsx
ignore the errors but if you hover over `value` on line 59. that's what I'm struggling to fix

Comment: @RedBaron - that is definitely a tough one. You could add another generic parameter `O` to `SekectWithQuery` which could either be `Option` or `Array<Option>` and also pass it down to `SelectWithQueryProps` as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJXpZN). If this is not feasible for you, the only other thing I can think of would to just assert that `value` is `Option & Array<Option>` with `value as Option & Array<Option>`.

Comment: your second suggestion seems to work so will go with that. many thanks for persisting through with that! marking as correct and upvoting now!